# Geohashing returns the same position for different hashes

Tags: python, geohashing

I'm using Geohash library in python. Consider this code:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Geohash
>>> Geohash.decode("u3qcr")
('52.3', '21.1')
>>> Geohash.decode("u3qcx")
('52.3', '21.1')
```

Why do I get the same result for different hashes? Id expect the as we have different last letter we'd get different rectangles. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the given precision, the coordinates are the same for both hashes. Check

```
>>> Geohash.decode_exactly("u3qcx")
(52.31689453125, 21.07177734375, 0.02197265625, 0.02197265625)
>>> Geohash.decode_exactly("u3qcr")
(52.27294921875, 21.07177734375, 0.02197265625, 0.02197265625)
>>>
```

Compare [the source](https://github.com/vinsci/geohash/blob/master/Geohash/geohash.py) for how the rounding in `Geohash.decode()` is calculated.

Comment: My output is : `(52.27294921875, 21.07177734375)` and `(52.31689453125, 21.07177734375)` so he used external library(for Linux:`apt-get install python-geohash` without rounding !).

Comment: same function exists for pygeohash. Saved my day. thanks.
```import pygeohash
exact_output = pygeohash.decode_exactly('tc0y3yc')
```

gives (6.7613983154296875, 79.88365173339844, 0.0006866455078125, 0.0006866455078125)